# What is the best approach when an opponent's queen is in the center and all of their pieces are developed?

Tags: opening, tactics, queens, development

I have played several games where my opponent's queen is somehow placed in the center of the board. However, this type of aggressive move positions my king in a dangerous spot. I can't castle because the queen can work with a bishop and provoke a checkmate. My other pieces are vulnerable to an attack because of their early piece development. I keep getting check after check because my king is in the center. It forces me to use my other valuable pieces to defend my king. This will eventually result in allowing my opponent to break my defense and slowly take out my pieces or, even worse, force my pieces to retreat. What is the best approach when this type of situation is encountered?

Comment: Are there a few representative games you could post to illustrate the types of positions and gameplay you are referring to?

Comment: When this type of situation is encountered, you have already lost, so your best approach is to resign.

Answer (score 3):

The best approach is to prevent it.  If you haven't castled, and your opponent's pieces are developed, you've already made several grave mistakes.

Post your game and we'll review it.

There are a number of openings that are known to result in good positions.  Do you know which one you play?

EDIT - @toby ok, for what you do, is learn how to play the Ruy Lopez and Queen's Gambit with white.  Learn the Grunfeld and Caro-Kann and play them when you have the black pieces.  These are well known and solid openings. They will prevent the situation in which you find yourself.

Comment: @Tony Ennis, I'm not sure where to find my game history. But, I think my question is pretty clear on what I want to know. Tell me what is the best aproach to prevent it.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan it's a question. the OP's question doesn't provide enough information to allow us to really help.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan, I've flagged his answer.

Comment: @TobyHarnish edited

Comment: @TonyEnnis no harm done.  (+1)

Comment: @TobyHarnish I'm not sure a flag is warranted but ok. I think Tony Harnish is just trying to get clarification (i.e. you edit question) so he can better answer you.